# Loop in Nodejs EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have a nodejs application with bootstrap. The bootstrap cards are to be placed as 3 in a row and as many as data in column. I tried that with two for loops but the data is getting repeated in each row. I am not able to figure out how to make that happen.

My EJS code is

```
<% for(var i=0; i<details.length; i++) { %>
          <div class="row">
            <% for(var j=0; j<3; j++) { %>
              <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="card border-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title"><%= details[i].name %></h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Location : <%= details[i].location %><br>
                          City: <%= details[i].city %><br>
                          Available: <%= details[i].available %><br>
                          Phone No: <%= details[i].phone %></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% } %>
          </div>
        <% } %>
```

Just for representation, I want the cards to show my data in this way:  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can get away with just one loop. To get the row logic correct, just stick a check on the loop counter `i` to see if you are on index 0, 3, 6, etc, and then if you are you can emit a row.

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) { %>
  <% if (i === 0 || i % 3 === 0) { %>
    <div class="row">
  <% } %>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card border-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
             <h4 class="card-title"><%= details[i].name %></h4>
                <p class="card-text">Location : <%= details[i].location %><br>
                  City: <%= details[i].city %><br>
                  Available: <%= details[i].available %><br>
                  Phone No: <%= details[i].phone %>
                </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% if (i % 3 === 2 || i === details.length - 1) { %>
    </div>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but now I am getting error as "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: My bad, I had the logic screwed up the first go around. You need to make sure whatever is accessing `details` isn't outside the bounds of the `details` length. I refactored to use a `while()` loop for the outer, and then a `for` loop for the inner.

Comment: Annnd another refactor, it's been a long day... You can just use one loop, and then setup a conditional to spit out a row at index 0, 3, 6, etc...

Comment: There's a logic error here. It should check if i % 3 == 2 to emit the closing tag for the row, otherwise every third card will be in its own row, and the others will not be enclosed in any row.

Comment: @scgrn good eye! Updated with your corrections.

Comment: Just one more thing: The closing tag condition should be if (i % 3 === 2 || i === details.length - 1), otherwise the closing tag will not be emitted if the array length is not a multiple of three.